# How to save to database a user's response to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a form where I save user settings and there's one part where the user orders two list with the things they are most happy and most unhappy with. For example:

What factors are most important?

1. Salary (5)
2. Balance  (4)
3. Growth (3)
4. Perks   (2)
5. Manager  (1)

What are you most happy with?

1. Manager (1)
2. Growth  (2)
3. Perks (3)
4. Balance (4)
5. Salary (5)

So the user can drag and drop the list to his preference and now I need to rate the response (sum the numbers in front) and save the top 3. (In this case it would be Salary (10), Balance(8) and Perks(5) (Growth also has 5 points but it has less points on the second question))

After this the user clicks submit and I want to save on a user_topics table. I've created the migrations like so:

```
class CreateUserTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_topics do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :topic

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class UserTopic < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :topic
end
```

So I need to save this and every user has only 3 top topics at a time.

My _form_html.erb has a submit button:

```
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Finished", class: 'button btn-standard' %>
  </div>
```

Which triggers the users_controller.erb

```
 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your information has been updated!' }
      else
        format.html { render :core_info }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

end

I'm confused to where should I create and implement the method to do the logic and save the data.

Comment: In order to give a more accurate response, I need to ask a question: 
Imagine you save the data already in whichever form is needed, then can you give me an example of how it will be updated in the future?
I'm asking because as far as I can tell this seems more like a design issue rather than how to save your data (model, structure, etc).

Comment: So, whenever the user goes into the setting page, they can change the order of the items and it needs to change every time the user does that. But he can only have 3 "top topics" at a time,

Comment: Check out Toby 1 Kenobi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to do this.

You haven't been clear about how the topic information is collected in the form and passed to the controllers. Perhaps you have the data as fields in the `user_params` that don't actually correspond to columns in the users table.

If this is the case then what I would do is create a PORO that takes the `user_params` and removes those fields processes them and creates the relevant `UserTopic` objects, then returns the `user_params` without those extra fields. The users controller would call on this PORO to do it's thing to the params before it passes them to `User.create`.

If it was me, I'd do things a bit differently. Instead of only saving the 3 top topics I'd save all the information the user provided, then whenever I need the three top topics I'd do the calculation for that on the fly. This way if you decide to change how you calculate the score for topics, you can without having to get the users to re-enter the data.

To do this I'd make the `UserTopic` model have a happiness integer and an importance integer, then I'd join every topic to each user with the scores the user gave. You might be able to do this in the form using `accepts_attributes_for` but it would be a bit fiddly getting it to work with the user ordering two lists.

Then I'd have a `top_topics(amount=3)` method in the `User` class that does the calculations to get the top n topics for that user.